# Whether Sonar supports the below languages?

Tags: java, plugins, sonarqube

I would like to know whether sonar analyze the below javascript,jquery,knockout.js,languages? if yes is it licensed or free. Can you please share me the link to download this plugin so that we can integrate to analyze this project. We are using sonarqube 5.0.1 version. We are fine for latest sonarqube 6.2 version, But need to know whether it supports?

Answer (score 2):

You can check the link below for a list of Plugins available for Sonar

https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Plugin+Library